# Searching entire column and counting matches with criteria in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Basically i have two sheets, one worksheet with the criteria that will be used to search and count how many matches there are in another worksheet. Criteria is in two columns, for example each column has a type of pet dog and cat. The two pets in each row should be treated as a pair or set.

```
Unique Criteria 
Pet1    Pet2
Dog Cat
Dog Hamster
Cat Hamster
Snake   Dog
Parrot  GoldFish
```

I want to count how many students have the specific combinations of the Criteria next to each other for example Dog and Cat, how many have Dog and Hamster, How many have Parrot GoldFish.

In the other sheet it has a list of students about 8 columns. Two of the columns are the pets they have. I want to match with these columns and count how many have a Dog and Hamster.

So far i have been able to match the first set of criteria with the first student. I am lost at this point on what would be the best way to search the entire two columns and count how many student have a Dog and Cat and then display the count amount.

Sorry if i didnt explain perfectly! Thanks in advance!!

```
Sub CountProgPlan()
Dim Prog As Range
Set Prog = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a6")
Dim Plan As Range
Set Plan = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("b6")
Dim StudentType As String
StudentType = "F05"
If Prog = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2") And Plan = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2") And StudentType = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d2") Then
MsgBox "Postive"
Else
MsgBox "This is Negative"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need VBA for this? Both `=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B15="Dog")*(C1:C15="Hamster"))` or `=COUNTIFS(B1:B15,"Dog",C1:C15,"Hamster")` return a count. If it can be both ways (Dog & Hamster, Hamster & Dog) you can write it both ways and add the two formulas

Comment: With the update, JvDv's suggestion shuold be even more appropriate.  `=CountIfs(Source!$B:$B, Criteria!A2, Source!$C:$C, Criteria!B2)` where Source is the source sheet for your data, assuming col B is where pet named 1 shows up and col C is where petname 2 shows up, and Criteria is the sheet where your newly added list exists, where A2 & B2 are dynamic references so you can drag the formula down.

Comment: I need it in VBA as it is part of a larger automation of a data dump i am given. Essentially i am trying to count how many students that have a Parrot and Goldfish are considered F05 Students (Student type is a column on its own. Any help with the VBA code would be much appreciated.